# Checkbox checked using javascript on tcpdf

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, tcpdf

I have a question about javascript that I using in TCPDF to generate PDF.
I use mix of php native and codeigniter with MySQL database to develop my App.

My Soryboard :
I have a field in my table like this that represntated like this :

```
$dataKind = $d['kindOf_request'];
// This code will be return a string like this : **Login, Printer, Monitor, Computer, Network, Other**
```

So, I use Javascript to split this string to convert into an array.

You know, TCPDF can write html. How to manipulated a checkbox that will be checked if matching with Element of this array. This is the code :

```
$dataKind = $d['kindOf_request'];
$html = <<<EOD
          <body>
          <form action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login"     value="Login"    > Login
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer"   value="Printer"  > &nbsp; Printer
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor"   value="Monitor"  > &nbsp; Monitor
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer"  value="Computer" > &nbsp; Computer
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network"   value="Network"  > &nbsp; Network
            <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Lain-lain" value="Lain-lain"> Other
             </form>
            </body>
 EOD;

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 10, '', '', $html, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $fill = false, $reseth = true, $align = 'L', $autopadding = false);


 $js = <<<EOD
        var str = "$dataJenis";
        var res = str.split(" ");

        for (var i=0, item; item=res[i]; i++) {
            item = item.replace(/,/g, "");
            /*if item == id checkbox, then : 
                checkbox will be checked
            */

            if (item == document.getElement ...) {

                    // Confused
                    # code...
                }    

            //app.alert(item);
        }
 EOD;
        $pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

So million thanks for the help ...